# Exception of type 'System.Windows.Forms.AxHost+InvalidActiveXStateException' was thrown

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, fingerprint, axhost

I am getting an error in my simple project.

This is my code:

```
if (axZKFPEngX1.InitEngine() == 0) {
    label1.Text = "Connected";
}
else {
    label1.Text = "Connection Failed";
}
```

I already added reference composites `AxInterop.ZKFPEngXControl` and `Interop.ZKFPEngXControl`.

While debugging, I click the button, and a warning appears:

> InvalidActiveXStateException was handled.
>
> "Exception of type 'System.Windows.Forms.AxHost+InvalidActiveXStateException' was thrown"**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

try to call `CreateControl()` from your component first.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by **Constantin** is Fulfill your requirement but here I wanted to add one more thing with it.
If you wanted to reflected this changes via all the threads and not only by calling thread (in multiple thread scenario)  then use

```
CreateControl();
InitWB();
SkinAllThreads();
```

Actually in multiple threading scenario if your skinning code is in one of the thread then may be it is not reflect change for other current thread so at that time  this code is play important role in it.

Here is some Documents I mention kindly go through it for reference  :

1. [initwb() method](http://www.stardock.com/products/directskin/docs/initwb.html)
2. [DirectSkin other Methods](http://www.stardock.com/products/directskin/documentation.asp)
3. [Adding Direct Skin to Application](http://www.stardock.com/corporatesolutions/DirectSkin/pdf/DirectSkin_AddingDS.pdf)