# System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.InvalidActiveXStateException was unhandled

Tags: c#, exception, activex

I am continuously struggling with this exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.InvalidActiveXStateException' occurred in AxInterop.SBXPCLib.dll

any help please, am i missing some thing.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Try this,it will solve your problem:**

For each and every active x control, it is needed to create it first, so that all the events and handles should be initialized.

So try this:

`axMDocView1.CreateControl()`

Comment: Where to give this line of code. I am getting this error while running my windows applciation

Comment: for more clarification - this being used before connecting to device.... am talking about zk4500

Comment: I had some crashes on my application when disposing one of my AxMap control. Adding CreateControl() when creating the control in question solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer by **Vishal** is Fulfill your requirement but here I wanted to add one more thing with it. If you wanted to reflected this changes via all the threads and not only by calling thread (in multiple thread scenario) then use

```
axMDocView1.CreateControl();
axMDocView1.SkinAllThreads();
```

Actually in multiple threading scenario if your skinning code is in one of the thread then may be it is not reflect change for other current thread so at that time this code is play important role in it.

Comment: For better understand kindly go through similar [question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240523/exception-of-type-system-windows-forms-axhostinvalidactivexstateexception-was)