# Stop AxWindowsMediaPlayer programmatically via button click

Tags: c#, wpf, axwindowsmediaplayer

How can I stop the AxWindowsMediaPlayer manually on button click? I am developing an application in WPF and using VS 2015.

```
<WindowsFormsHost x:Name="winhost" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" Visibility="Hidden">
    <ax:AxWindowsMediaPlayer x:Name="axwmp" /> 
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a commandbinding on the button, or watching the button click event programmatically, you can execute this command:

```
axWindowsMediaPlayerObject.Ctlcontrols.stop();
```

Here is my code, how i tried it:

**WPF - MainWindow**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">Test</Button>

    <WindowsFormsHost Grid.Row="1" x:Name="winhost" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent">
        <ax:AxWindowsMediaPlayer x:Name="axwmp" />
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private AxWindowsMediaPlayer mPlayer;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mPlayer = axwmp;
        mPlayer.BeginInit();
        mPlayer.EndInit();
        mPlayer.Ctlenabled = true;
        mPlayer.URL = @"http://www.mediacollege.com/audio/tone/files/100Hz_44100Hz_16bit_30sec.mp3";
        mPlayer.Ctlcontrols.play();
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mPlayer.Ctlcontrols.stop();
    }
}
```

Btw, you need to have the MediaPlayer.exe outputed to your exe.

Comment: @DebugMe_77, please provide us your code, we could find where it stucks. Maybe you are getting an error message? Provide what you have, to get good help.

Comment: i am getting error like "A Handled Exception just occured : Exception of type ' System.Windows.Forms.Axhost + InvalidActiveXstateException' was thrown. This Error is coming when i click on button , on which i write the code for stop the axWindowsMediaPlayerObject. Please help.

Comment: @DebugMe_77, please read [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22727826/4198052) answer. Maybe this could help you. If not, edit your QUESTION and add some sample code.

Comment: Please Review following code : -                                                                                                                <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="winhost"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          Background="Transparent"
                          Visibility="Hidden">

            <ax:AxWindowsMediaPlayer x:Name="axwmp" />

        </WindowsFormsHost> this is my Xaml Page .

Comment: On Xaml.cs page  I write the code for stop the axWindowsMediaPlayerObject i,e Axwmp and the code on button click is given below.  i,e       axWmp.Ctlcontrols.stop();      could you please tell me the where i am wrong.

Comment: Hello Marius , have you find Something.

Comment: @DebugMe_77, I just tried it myself, but I dont get any error.
Maybe you can try to initialise the player manually. So you need to do these steps:
     mPlayer.BeginInit();
     mPlayer.EndInit();
     mPlayer.Ctlenabled = true;

Comment: Ok thanx.but would u plz tell me that where i am stucking.

Comment: this problem is not fixed yet. problem is persist right now.i donot know what is the problem here.

Comment: @DebugMe_77, do you have the exe and all files (dlls) which are mentioned in [THIS](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/497004/Using-Windows-Media-Player-Control-in-WPF) article?
Maybe you can try to add this line to your initialisation of the player "            mPlayer.CreateControl();"